# Why importing transparent images as plane looks like an opaque plane?

Tags: add-on, import, image

When i imported a tranparent png by images as planes, uts looks like an opaque plane and I cant see the picture. Please check this out and suggest me a solution. I am using 2.83 version. I am a beginner in blender. So kindly help

Comment: Add some screenshots about what view you are in, the result you got to have a better understanding...Btw, try viewing it in the rendered view..If u want in object view, you will have to change the view to textured mode in properties tab.. please add screeshots so that we can suggest you solution

Comment: Please help others help you by [adding an image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/183910/edit) of your problem. It it is easier to visualize problems that can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded a texture make sure you have an opacity map downloaded along with the texture and then you can follow this node setup:***(Make sure to delete the default node setup of the image plane)***
[image: Node setup][image]

this is an example for opacity map:

the area marked black will appear transparent
(WILL ONLY WORK IN CYCLES ENGINE)